# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My error is :

> Notice: Undefined variable: nume in
>   C:\wamp64\www\proiectphp\editarecontp.php on line 44

but i check all my lines and i can't figure out where i'm wrong ... i read all answers from here about this type of error, i try also with empty error, $_post, to put in sql, i tested the connection and everything it's ok at it. 
I can't undestand where is the problem ...

Code here :

```
<form action="editarecontp.php" method="POST" >
Nume: <input type="text" name="formnume" value="<?php echo $row["numegraf"];?>"></br>
Prenume: <input type="text" name="formprenume" value="<?php echo $row["prenumegraf"];?>"></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="formemail" value="<?php echo $row["emailgraf"];?>"></br>
Pass: <input type="password" name="formpass" value="<?php echo $row["passgraf"];?>">    </br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Salveaza">
</form>
<?php 
if(!$db) echo mysql_error();
$dbselect=mysqli_select_db($db,'proiectphp');
if(!$dbselect) echo mysql_error();
if (isset($_POST['formnume'])) {
$nume = isset($_POST['formnume']);
```

.....etc

```
$sqlmodifica="UPDATE graficieni SET numegraf=$nume , prenumegraf=$prenume , emailgraf=$email , passgraf=$passw WHERE usernamegraf=$userr";
mysqli_query($db,$sqlmodifica);
```

Comment: please send your all code here

Comment: Which one is line 44 in the above code ?

Comment: `` its double ...

Comment: 44 is the one with $sqlmodifica

Comment: And which variable is undefined post the variable name to?

Comment: {``$nume = isset($_POST['formnume']);`   .... remove single ` from $nume

Comment: 1. Mixing APIs here, `mysql_` and `mysqli_` is like apples and oranges - different. 2) `isset($_POST['formnume'])` is a boolean true/false, that most likely doesn't do what you think it does.  See documentation for `isset()`. 3) You need to show some code - most likely the closing bracket of `if (isset($_POST['formnume'])) {` is placed before the query is made.

Comment: all from sql like $nume, $prenume etc. but i defined them after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of `$nume = isset($_POST['formnume']);`, it should be `$nume = $_POST['formnume'];`.
isset function returns a a boolean value. You are assigning `$nume` as a boolean value and than using that in the query.

Another possible reason for this error is that there is no default value defined for `$nume` and it has been declared in an `if` block.
You may be accessing it in an outer block after `if` block and in case `$_POST['formnume']` is not set, $nume will be never be defined.
Hope that helps.